# In Yupitergrad 2, How do I defeat the shield drone?

Tags: yupitergrad-2

In Yupitergrad 2: the Lost Station, I have just acquired the miniguns, and now I am trying to get past the adjacent room that has a single, button-activated drone that is protected by a glowing shield. I cannot figure out what I'm supposed to do here. I can pour endless minigun fire into the drone, but I see no sign this is doing it any harm. I don't see anything else in the room I can interact with either, and there's no way past the room until I defeat the drone. All that happens is I endlessly pour minigun fire into the drone, while trying to dodge its shots as best I can, and this goes on and on until eventually it gets enough shots through to kill me. Then I have to start over, and then it all happens again. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured this out, but it sure took me a while. The shield is completely immune to minigun fire, but can easily be brought down using the original, generally-less-powerful gun that you acquire early in the game. You **must** use the original gun to get past the shield. Once the shield is down, you can use the minigun to finish them off.

This took me *forever* to figure out, because it just didn't occur to me that a weaker gun could take down the shield when a much stronger one could not. (Plus, it's hard to get past "Woohoo! Dual-weilded miniguns!") Now that I understand this, my approach is to enter any drone-guarded room with the old gun in one hand and the minigun in the other.